# android - getting headers from URL causing my application crash

Tags: android, httpclient

I need to get all headers from a url. to do so i am using the following code

```
try {

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://onlineservice.banglalinkgsm.com/Construction.htm");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
    for (Header header : headers) {

        Result =Result +"Key : " + header.getName() 
            + " ,Value : " + header.getValue();

}
catch (Exception e) {  }
```

but when i run the app it crashs. I can not figure out where i have made mistake. please help me.
currently i am adding httpclient-4.3 library. I also have tested for httpclient-4.3.2 library.

here is my logcat

```
02-09 14:27:10.527: E/dalvikvm(7780): Could not find class   'org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager', referenced from method org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:460)
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at com.example.headerread.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:93)
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-09 14:27:10.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 14:27:10.602: E/AppErrorDialog(504): Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance
```

Comment: Remove the try/catch and check the stacktrace in the error log

Comment: @fiddler. how can u say this without knowing the error?

Comment: I say this precisely because i dont know the error :) but putting an empty try/catch really doesnt help finding the issue

Comment: @Imdad... hey buddy... better post logcat..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't declare your `soapResult` variable and confusing `Result` with `soapResult`.

Try to replace:

```
    for (Header header : headers) {

    Result =soapResult +"Key : " + header.getName() 
        + " ,Value : " + header.getValue();
```

by

```
    String soapResult;
    for (Header header : headers) {

        soapResult =soapResult +"Key : " + header.getName() 
        + " ,Value : " + header.getValue();
```

Comment: sorry, that is my editing problem. i think my problem is in the line   HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();    @fiddler